# How to Play MJP Files in C# WinForm by using Vlc.DotNet?

Tags: c#

How to Play MJP Files in C# by using Vlc.DotNet ? here is my code-

```
        VlcControl player = new VlcControl();
        panel1.Controls.Add(player);
        player.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
        player.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
        player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        player.Name = "test";
        player.Rate = 0.0F;
        player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);         
        player.Play(new FileInfo(@"E:\Sample\2.mjp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me:

```
    private void Play()
    {
        if (vlcVideo.IsPlaying)
        {
            vlcVideo.Stop();
        }
        string path = @"E:\Sample\2.mjp";
        LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(path);
        vlcVideo.Media = media;
        vlcVideo.Play();
    }
```